# trying to join 3 statements together in a select case

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to join these 3 statements together. I can get two to work but not the third.

*Check* is looking to see if the 5th character = a,b,c,d.

*Check0* is looking to see if characterS 2-9 are all numbers.

*Check3* is looking to see if the first 3 characters are numbers.

Desired effect

*Before* >            **After**

Check 0 *e01730101.pdf* > **S-173-0101**

Check3 *173d00510.pdf* > **S-173-D005**

Check *e173d0061.pdf* > **S-173-D006**

Right now Check0 is not working. When I run the code it seems to skip my Case 13 Check0 statement. Anyway i can write this so the 3 checks are not conflicting each other?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Convert()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim val As String, Check, Check0, Check3
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each aCell In rng.Cells
Select Case Len(aCell)
   'Case 12 left out
    Case 13
        Check = Mid(aCell, 5, Len(aCell) - 12)
        If Check = "a" Or Check = "b" Or Check = "c" Or Check = "d" Then 'Existing Standard
        val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 13) & Mid(aCell, 2, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 5, Len(aCell) - 9)

            Check0 = IsNumeric(Mid(aCell, 2, Len(aCell) - 5)) '|||PROBLEM|||
            ElseIf Check0 = True Then 'Existing Three Line Diagrams
            val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 9)
            End If

                Check3 = IsNumeric(Left(aCell, 3))
                If Check3 = True Then 'Standard after page 9
                val = "S-" & Mid(aCell, 1, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 9)
                End If
        Check = ""
        Check0 = ""
        Check3 = ""
   'Case 14 left out
    Case Else 'All other pages
        val = "_Mod " & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 4)
End Select

val = UCase(val)

val = val & " " & aCell.Offset(, 2) & aCell.Offset(, 3)

aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = val
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Which two work?

Comment: @Busse the way it is now, `Check0` does not work.

Comment: What do you mean 'does not work'  ?

Comment: Just checking to make sure it's written as intended. The `Check0` will only get hit if it meets the prior `If` Criteria: `If Check = "a" Or Check = "b" Or Check = "c" Or Check = "d" Then`.  OR if it is a Boolean value set to `True`. Is this intended? Where do you apply the value of `True` or `False` to `Check0`?

And as @RobinMackenzie mentioned, please make sure you update your original question with _HOW_ it does not work.  Does it error, does it not get a value assigned to it, etc.

Comment: If `Check` is not a, b, c or d then you then look at `Check0` but only set the value of `Check0` if `Check` is a, b, c or d. This is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `Check0` variable is not initialised when you check it. It would be best to first do all your three checks and only then perform the `If...ElseIf...`.

Secondly, this expression is using the wrong parts of the input string:

```
val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 9)
```

I don't really understand why you use `Len(aCell) - something`, since it is known that the length is 13. Certainly `Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 13)` is quite useless, as it will be the empty string.

Here is a correction with some other optimisations (`pos` is a `Long`):

```
    Case 13
        Check = InStr("abcd", Mid(aCell, 5, 1))
        Check0 = IsNumeric(Mid(aCell, 2, 8))
        Check3 = IsNumeric(Left(aCell, 3))
        pos = IIf(Check3, 1, _
              IIf(Check, 2, _
              IIf(Check0, 3, 0)))
        val = IIf(pos, "S-" & Mid(aCell, pos, 3) & "-" & Mid(aCell, pos+3, 4), "??")
```